# Is it possible to determine if a UIImage is stretchable?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimage

I'm trying to reuse a small chunk of code inside a custom button class.  For this to work I need to pass in non stretchable images (an icon) or a stretchable image (a 'swoosh').  Within the code I need to set the rect to draw the height so I'd like, ideally, to simply determine if the image is stretchable or not?  If it isn't I draw it at the size of the image, if not I draw at the bounds of the containing rect.

From my investigation so far capInsets (iOS 5) or leftCapWidth/topCapHeight (pre iOS 5) are not useful for this.

Is there something buried in the core or quartz information I can use?

Just curious, for now I'm coding around it with an extra parameter.

** I've since read through CGImageRef and the CI equivalent **

As far as I can tell there is no such information that we can access to identify such images, which begs the question how does the OS know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to detect this unless you have some intense image analysis (which won't be 100% correct).  UIImage is essentially some pixels with meta-information, all obtained from the file that you loaded it from.  No file formats would have that information.

However, you can encode some information into the file name of the image.  If you have an image called foo.png that is stretchable, why not call it foo.stretch.png?  Your loading routines can analyse the file name and extract meta-information that you can associate with the UIImage (see http://labs.vectorform.com/2011/07/objective-c-associated-objects/ for associated objects) or by creating your own class that composites a UIImage with meta-information.

Good luck in your research.

Comment: I've been informed that in android it is a sub class of whatever represents an image normally.  Grr. :P  It's easy to code around by setting a bool stretchable property in the UIView subclass that I'm using to render inside the button, then checking that in the setter and drawRect routines.  So it was a problem I'd already technically solved.  I was just curious.

Answer (score 0):

When u create UIImage*, its .size property is absolute.
If u mean stretchable to your button view. just check scale for example.

```
- (BOOL) stretchableImage:(UIImage*)aImage toView:(UIView*)aView{
    CGFloat scaleW = aView.size.width/aImage.size.width;
    CGFloat scaleH = aView.size.height/aImage.size.height;

    if (scaleW == scaleH){
       if (scaleW < 1)
           return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: That won't work for me.  It's an image defined by stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth/resizableImageWithCapInsets.  So it would always be smaller than the containing rect.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it's class.

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back"];
NSString *imgClass = NSStringFromClass(img.class);
    
UIImage *imgStretch = [img stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10 topCapHeight:10];
NSString *imgStrClass = NSStringFromClass(imgStretch.class);
    
NSLog(@"Normal class:\t%@\nStretchable class:\t%@",imgClass,imgStrClass);
```

Console:

```
Normal class:       UIImage
Stretchable class:  _UIResizableImage
```